# Can't install PinterestSDK

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, pinterest

In my Podfile, I tried to install PinterestSDK using these pod lines.

```
pod 'PinterestSDK', '~> 1.0'
pod "PinterestSDK", :git => "https://github.com/pinterest/ios-pdk.git"
pod "PinterestSDK", :git => "git@github.com:pinterest/ios-pdk.git"
```

None of these works. This is the error.

```
[!] Error installing PinterestSDK
[!] Failed to download 'PinterestSDK': [!] /usr/local/bin/git clone https://github.com/pinterest/ios-pdk.git /var/folders/wt/nbn7rbwd5yz0fvmlvhs6ptfc0000gn/T/d20210506-3226-i5p1tn --template= --single-branch --depth 1

Cloning into '/var/folders/wt/nbn7rbwd5yz0fvmlvhs6ptfc0000gn/T/d20210506-3226-i5p1tn'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/pinterest/ios-pdk.git/' not found
```

As the error says, I guess my first question is, Is the library still active? I could not access also the Pinterest Github repository(https://github.com/pinterest/ios-pdk.git). I'm not sure if my internet provider is blocking the library or perhaps it's not available in public already.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The repository seems to be deleted, maybe you could try some forked version, like https://cocoapods.org/pods/PinterestSDK_5

Comment: @BoygeniusDexter That explains it. Thanks for the link, guess I'll have to use the forked version.

Answer (score 2):

So it seems that the library is deleted. For workaround, you can use this forked version.

```
pod 'PinterestSDK_5'
```